# Jupyter traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, jupyter

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rohzr\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 235, in _resolve_classes
klass = self._resolve_string(klass)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\rohzr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 2025, in _resolve_string
return import_item(string)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\rohzr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server.contents'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rohzr\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\rohzr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 280, in launch_instance
super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\rohzr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 1051, in launch_instance
app = cls.instance(**kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\rohzr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 575, in instance
inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\rohzr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1311, in __new__
inst.setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\rohzr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1354, in setup_instance
super(HasTraits, self).setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\rohzr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1330, in setup_instance
init(self)
File "C:\Users\rohzr\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 226, in instance_init
self._resolve_classes()
File "C:\Users\rohzr\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 238, in _resolve_classes
warn(f"{klass} is not importable. Is it installed?", ImportWarning)
TypeError: warn() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'stacklevel'
```

I have tried to update through conda and also tried to reinstall anaconda to fix the problem but there is no success .

Comment: [Here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/issue-in-jupyter-notebook/21576/2?u=fomightez) posted the same issue, I think, with some suggestions for resolving it.

Comment: The issue arises because of multiple python versions. I suggest to completely remove `C:\Users\rohzr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311`

Answer (score 0):

run this command on anaconda prompt.

pip uninstall traitlets

pip install traitlets==5.9.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).