# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server.contents'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 235, in _resolve_classes
klass = self._resolve_string(klass)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Cristian Valiante\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 2025, in _resolve_string
return import_item(string)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Cristian Valiante\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server.contents'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Cristian Valiante\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 280, in launch_instance
super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Cristian Valiante\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 1051, in launch_instance
app = cls.instance(**kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Cristian Valiante\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 575, in instance
inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Cristian Valiante\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1311, in __new__
inst.setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Cristian Valiante\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1354, in setup_instance
super(HasTraits, self).setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Cristian Valiante\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1330, in setup_instance
init(self)
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 226, in instance_init
self._resolve_classes()
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 238, in _resolve_classes
warn(f"{klass} is not importable. Is it installed?", ImportWarning)
TypeError: warn() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'stacklevel'
```

Thank you for help ! :)

I have tried installing and uninstalling and it didnt work.

Comment: From your comment below Goku's answer, it looks, unlike [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77477555/8508004), installing traitlets 5.9 fixed your current issue. If you come across additional problems down the road keep in mind that as pointed out in the comment [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77477555/jupyter-notebook-not-opening-from-anaconda-navigator#comment136591366_77477555) and in comments to other similar questions such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77507736/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77402235/8508004) that you may need to ultimately ...

Comment: <continued> deal with the multiple Python versions you appear to have. I.e., `C:\Users\Cristian Valiante\AppData\Roaming\Python` vs `C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\. (That last part basically reiterates what [FlyingTeller said here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5012099/flyingteller).)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a known error:

The Workaround:
Uninstall the Recent Problematic Release (v5.10.0) and Install the Prior Version (v5.9.0).

Command Line:

```
pip uninstall traitlets
pip install traitlets==5.9.0
```

Git links:

https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/24436#issuecomment-1723328100

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/7048

Comment: I ran that command line in the Anaconda prompt, as administrator. It worked perfectly. Thank you so much !

Comment: If you migrated to Notebook 7, then this error disappears at least with respect to my Ubuntu 23.10. Whether all the existing extensions work or not with Notebook 7 is a different story, though.

Comment: Thanks for linking back to my original post on GitHub to give props.Glad to see this was posted to StackOverflow.  I should have done the same, but at the time, I was new to phython and had no idea how many people would benefit from the workaround.  I've since gone back to my C# & T-SQL world, where I am far more comfortable.  I thought I was a cheeky good little dev, up until open source kicked my butt!  It was too hard for me to work in.  I definitely have a newfound respect for you guys, that's for sure!

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the problem is not with traitlets, but with notebook. Update that to a version that is newer than 6.5.6 will fix this problem:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/7048#issuecomment-1724851639

Comment: Thank you so much, it did the job for me! `pip install notebook==6.5.6`