# Obscure Anaconda Jupyter Launch Error - Full Traceback Included

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I am getting the following error when I try to open jupyter from my base anaconda environment. I have not done anything to mess with the install, so I am not sure why this is happening. This morning I was trying VS code to see if I liked using it with jupyter notebooks, and nothing would run, so I opened anaconda like I usually do and got this message when I try to run jupyter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\neall\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 235, in _resolve_classes
klass = self._resolve_string(klass)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\neall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 2015, in _resolve_string
return import_item(string)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\neall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 33, in import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server.contents'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\neall\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\neall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 283, in launch_instance
super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\neall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 1073, in launch_instance
app = cls.instance(**kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\neall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 583, in instance
inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\neall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1292, in __new__
inst.setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\neall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1335, in setup_instance
super(HasTraits, self).setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\neall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1311, in setup_instance
init(self)
File "C:\Users\neall\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 226, in instance_init
self._resolve_classes()
File "C:\Users\neall\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 238, in _resolve_classes
warn(f"{klass} is not importable. Is it installed?", ImportWarning)
TypeError: warn() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'stacklevel'
```

I have tried:

- uninstalling/reinstalling anaconda
- deleting all jupyter files & info from my local PC
- restarting my PC

I donwloaded miniconda and that DID work, but I prefer to use the GUI and it was some weird version of jupyter where all of the icons where black and white. I am not sure if it was a new version ofjupyter or what!

Comment: If no one's said it already, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. I strongly recommend reading [ask] for tips like how to write a good title and showing what research you've done.

Comment: You seem to have the same **TWO issues** as I refer to in my comments below the original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77549493/8508004), or [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/hi-i-am-getting-this-launch-error-every-time-i-am-trying-to-open-jupyter-notebook-through-anaconda-i-even-tried-to-reinstall-anaconda-which-didn-t-help-can-someone-help-here-in-this-community/22328/2?u=fomightez), including the 'related'. You may have forgotten or not realized what you were doing with VS Code was messing up your Anaconda-installed things? ...

Comment: <continued> When you chose to use the Anaconda Distribution on your system, you opted into that being your main package manager. Please if you are using Anaconda, stick with only using Anaconda to update things unless there ins't a Anaconda recipe and only then do you resort to using `pip` and make sure you are in the Anaconda environment or Anaconda prompt.

Comment: @Wayne thanks man I will see if that is it, I think it is a jupyter issue tbh.

Comment: Yes, it is now. Also your environment is mixed and matched according to showing `C:\Users\neall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311` and `C:\Users\neall\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\`.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem on Ubuntu with a version that was running fine up t a while ago. Went back to it and nothing worked. Solution is definitely as @Wayne suggested. Follow the link in his reply and install the previous traitlets as per the instructions there.

FWIW Ubuntu 22.04.4LTS with current updates and upgrades - installation via pip3